# GA4 Newbie: how to create a custom dimension throug GTAG

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I want to create a custom dimension to analyze which type of clothing the customer purchased. So

1. I inserted into the JavaScript code of my webpages the following code:

   > gtag('set', {'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'purchase_type'}});
   >
   > gtag('event', 'purchase_event', {'purchase_type': 't_shirt'});
2. Through 'Admin > Custom definitions', I created a new dimension called 'purchase_type':

- Dimension name = Type of purchase
- Scope = User
- User property = purchase_type

Through 'Explore > Free form', I created a new a free-form exploration displaying the data in a table mode. In the 'Dimensions' list of the very left ("Variables" column), I imported the 'purchase_type' dimension. And then, a included it as a 'row' in the "Settings" row.

However, I've been waiting for one week (much more than the mandatory 48 hours), and I see only "(not set)" values for the period. I see "not set" for one single day of the last week, and for the whole week. I included "Active users" and "Event count" as 'Values'.

I expected to see "t_shirt" values in this table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it is an `event_property` rather than `user_property`

Answer (score 0):

Change the scope into `Event`. Pay attention to the **Nature of your Data**: The purchase type, such as 't_shirt', is tied to a specific event (or hit) – when a user buys a product. It is not necessarily an attribute of the user themselves, like their membership status or user preferences. This makes `Event` a more fitting scope. By setting the scope to `Event`, you ensure that every purchase event captures and sends the type of product purchased. This will give you a clearer picture of which clothing items are being purchased and how frequently.